# Praying at the Mosque Obligatory for Men?

Tags: salat

Assalamu Alaikum. I heard that praying at the mosque is obligatory for men and that prayers performed alone wouldn't be accepted. Is this true? I'm 15 and have school and homework so trying to go to the mosque every single time would be hectic. Plus there is no way my parents are going to allow me to go to the mosque every single time, every single day (especially for Isha and Fajr for safety concerns). Would these count as valid excuses? Jazak Allahu Khairun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not required to pray in the mosque. 
You can pray in your home or wherever you want 
"
فَوَلِّ وَجْهَكَ شَطْرَ الْمَسْجِدِ الْحَرَامِ وَحَيْثُ مَا كُنتُمْ فَوَلُّواْ وُجُوِهَكُمْ شَطْرَهُ 
"