# Is there a Quranic reference which indicates if man is obliged to pray his (daily) prayers in a mosque?

Tags: fiqh

I know this question has been ask before [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24798/praying-at-the-mosque-obligatory-for-men) by another person,

But the answer over there is not too reassuring for me and the question is similar but doesn't really cover the specifics of what I really want to know.

My question is, is there any **Quranic verses** (not hadiths) that Muslim Scholars usually use to refer to (or many scholars interpret it as) that in Islam, muslims (or at least male muslims) have the obligation to do the daily prayers in a Mosque (aka it's mandatory)? Which Quranic verses indicates that is an obligation and in what situation is it mandatory?

(note: please don't include verses that indicates it is mandatory to do prayer in the mosque but it turns out to actually be in the context of the Friday Prayer only)

Regards,

Comment: Why would you disregard the Hadiths? If you tend to do so, then the Quran doesn't even show the method of how to pray. Would you also say the present method of praying 'maybe' wrong as it isn't in any Quranic verse?

Comment: Because..I think it has been answered with hadith references somewhere else in this forum..that's why I said this question was different..

Comment: Your imagining things too far away...I haven't had any plans on asking about that..yet you already believe that I do..I don't have the mindset that every ruling has to be exactly determined in the Quran..I'm just asking whether it exist or not for that particular topic..I think you haven't notice that this question has been asked similarly in another thread..

Comment: @Tomsofty33 then I believe you should rephrase the title of your question because the way it is refers to what Ahmed understood. I understood it the way Ahmed did. Here's a better version: "Is there a Quranic reference which discusses if man is obliged to pray his prayers in a mosque?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Say: “My Lord hath commanded justice; and that ye set your whole selves (to Him) at every time and Masjid (place of worship), and call upon Him, making your devotion sincere as in his sight: such as he created you in the beginning, so shall ye return.” [7:29]

In has been said in this verse of the Glorious Qur’an that we should be sincere to Allah in the prayer and set ourselves to Him at every time and place of worship. Interesting thing is, in the original Arabic text, it says the word Masjid (literal English translation is mosque). So it is clearly said he that we should pray in areas which are known to be called “Masjids” by the Qur’an. So, it is preferable (if not mandatory) to pray in Masjids (areas that are built or occupied just in the intention that it is for Allah’s worship). However, some of the people may quote another verse.

> And We revealed to Mūsā (Moses) and his brother: “Have houses for your people in Egypt, and make your houses oriented, and establish Salah (prayer), and give good tidings to the believers.” [10:87]

In this scenario, Mufti Muhammad Taqi Usmani says: “This means that they should pray at their homes, and the obligation to attend the mosque for prayer has been relaxed for them due to the Pharoah’s oppression.” In this scenario, Prophets Mūsā and Hārūn (may peace be upon them both) have a special excuse because of Fir’awn’s oppression. There are not many Muslims oppressed by rulers that will possibly kill them if they pray to their God.

Comment: Then there's the ruling of shortening the prayer while you are travelling. A general ruling. In that it clearly doesn't indicate that you have to pray at masjid.but CMIIW.

Comment: The word by word translation says after the word every, it follows masjid. There is no word for time. How do you interpret the sentence "every" Masjid. One could, for example, foolishly say that means we must pray to every masjid? it's a bit confusing.

Comment: And the sentence "every time" in your version of the translation. What does that mean? Does "every time" we have to be at a masjid?

Comment: The word “Masjid” used in this Ayah is used in a special way. The word could be translated as time of worship or place of worship. The translation above contains both of the meanings. Setting ourselves to him can mean just having “Allah-Allah-Allah” in our hearts. As for other inquries you can ask someone else. I do not feel comfortable answering more questions right now.

Comment: If it's every time of worship I would understand but If it's every place of worship (every masjid), it doesn't make sense to me..I mean how on earth would I do that? what do you think?

Comment: "The word “Masjid” used in this Ayah is used in a special way. The word could be translated as time of worship **OR** place of worship. " What's your reference for this?

Comment: Ok, if it's ok I'll post it in another question...