# Is it necessary to perform prostration after reciting verse of prostration (sajda) in Quran?

Tags: quran-recitation, sajda, sajdat-al-tilaawah

I have heard that Quran recitation will not be accepted until you haven't performed prostration (sajda) which occur during recitation of Quran. Is it necessary to perform sajda?

Comment: This should be covered at least in https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/53038/13438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its necessary to perform prostate because you are 
reciting the holy quran an following all the instructions and orders which is given to you by the Allah.
So when prostate arrives in quran you have to stop & close the holy quran do prostate and starts reciting again.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to perform prostrate as this is the essential part of Quran Pak and during recitation if a prostate occurred then we have to perform it. But there is a relaxation as it is not necessary to perform at the same time you can recite the whole Quran or whatever you want to recite a Para  you can perform prostrate which occurs during Quran recitation after that. And you also allow to perform all prostrates (as total 14) at the end of Quran as you finish it.

Answer (score -1):

Salam. in four chapters of Quran yes.
after the last verse in chapters 53 and 96.
after verse 37 of chapter 41 and also, after verse 15 of chapter 32.