# Is it obligatory to pray at the mosque for a baaligh?

Tags: salat, parents, prayer-timings

I wanted to ask whether it is obligatory to pray at the mosque for someone who has reached the age of puberty, and if his parents disagree with him even thoufh he lives close, then in this matter what does he have to do?

Comment: No it isn't see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32602/13438) and [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24798/13438).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sahih al-Bukhari » Book of Call to Prayers (Adhaan) >>Narrated Abu Huraira (RTA):](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/41)

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "By Him in Whose Hand my soul is I was
>   about to order for collecting firewood (fuel) and then order Someone
>   to pronounce the Adhan for the prayer and then order someone to lead
>   the prayer then I would go from behind and burn the houses of men who
>   did not present themselves for the (compulsory congregational) prayer.
>   By Him, in Whose Hands my soul is, if anyone of them had known that he
>   would get a bone covered with good meat or two (small) pieces of meat
>   present in between two ribs, he would have turned up for the `Isha'
>   prayer.'

We all know how soft our prophet (SAW) was, and he want to burn the houses of those who don't come for obligatory prayer to mosque.

I cannot say anything about your next question " if his parents disagree with him....."

Show this hadith and pray for them, may Allah guide all of us.

Comment: Brother, thank you for your answer but that doesn't really answer the question, besides, hadiths like this need context and other hadiths to support it that are like this hadith because when you really research this particular hadith you find out, the people who he ﷺ meant, were people who lived near the mosque at a distance where they could hear the Adhan naturally, so this doesn't really answer it... i want a conditionless answer and etc. And you had good explaining, but i didn't get the answer i wanted sorry brother✌...

Comment: Your question don't have any condition like distance or weather situation or hearing Adhan, I am living in USA, and it is not allowed to use the loudspeaker for adhan, I never heard adhan until I go to mosque. At the time of Prophet SAW city was small, call the adhan and everyone can hear that.

Comment: I understand what you mean but the conditions of it being obliged have to meet my condition for it to become obliged, and you didn't explain the conditions, sorry...✌